# Запуск синхронного Телеграм-бота асинхронно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, aiogram

Доброго времени суток.

Я тут на досуге запилил своего бота в Телеграме на ***python***. Но он получился синхронным из-за библиотеки ***telebot***. По-хорошему надо бы его на ***aiogram*** перевести, но пока времени не хватает. Подумал, как тут можно скостылить. Внимание, безумный вопрос - можно ли бота, написанного с помощью ***telebot***'a (там несколько функций), завернуть в обертку из ***aiogram*** для асинхронного выполнения? Вопрос чисто теоретический, интересно разобрать такой кейс. Сильно ли увеличится нагрузка на сервер, по сравнению с тем, если бы такой же функционал был реализован сразу на ***aiogram***? Какие еще подводные камни такого подхода, если он возможен?

Comment: Нельзя. Если бы было можно, то тогда у aiogram в принципе не было бы смысла его существования. А вам зачем вообще?

Comment: andreymal, по большей части - удовлетворить любопытство. Если возможна практическая реализация, реализовать - опыт. Вообще как-то telebot "асинхронизировать" можно?

Comment: (впрочем, на самом деле можно попытаться воткнуть gevent, но это так-то адовый костыль и я не уверен, будет ли telebot нормально с ним дружить)

Comment: andreymal, а через asyncio + requests вообще порно получится?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/asynchronous_telebot/timer_bot_async.py

Comment: Сергей Ш, выглядит просто, нужно будет проверить на деле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно столкнулся с AsyncTeleBot, может быть это то самое что делает асинхронным telebot, но сам ещё не успел попробовать

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]